# How would you select records from a table based on the difference between 'created' dates with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is some dummy data:

```
| ID  |     CREATED AT      |
| 367 | 2014-05-28 22:55:36 |
| 367 | 2014-05-28 22:57:06 |
| 369 | 2014-05-28 23:06:02 |
| 369 | 2014-05-28 23:08:05 |
| 369 | 2014-05-28 23:18:07 |
| 350 | 2014-05-28 23:12:56 |
| 261 | 2014-05-28 21:17:11 |
| 261 | 2014-05-29 22:27:43 |
```

What I'd like to select from this, are the IDs (obviously not a primary key in this case) where by the `created_at` date has a difference of 24hrs or more. So in the case with the above data, ID `261` has two records in there, which were created over 24hrs apart. So in the collection that is returned I'd want to see ID `261` in there.

What would be an effective way to structure this kind of query?

Comment: `...GROUP BY id HAVING HOUR(TIMEDIFF(MAX(CREATED_AT),MIN(CREATED_AT)))>=24`

Comment: @Mihai: And if there exists some records in between with a time gap of less than an hour, this would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slower option

```
SELECT id, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(created_at),MIN(created_at))) as seconds_difference
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING seconds_difference > 3600*24
```

faster option

```
SELECT t1.id, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t2.created_at, t1.created_at) as seconds_difference
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id AND t2.created_at > t1.created_at)
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t2.created_at, t1.created_at) > 3600*24
```

Comment: With the slower option I seem to be getting the following error: `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'TIMEDIFF'`

Comment: TIMEDIFF has 2 params,separated by comma minus doesnt belong,minor spelling in HAVING.

Comment: @HarryLawrence ups, change `-` to `,`. Anyway I recommend @Abhik answer, seems to be the fastest and easiest solution

Comment: This seems to be a great solution. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`ID` FROM `tbl` t1
INNER JOIN `tbl` t2 ON t1.`ID`=t2.`ID`
WHERE t2.`CREATED_AT` <= t1.`CREATED_AT` - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
```

Edit:

A better query (won't return a result if its min and max are 24 hours apart but there is something in the middle that is less than 24 hours apart):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`ID` FROM `test` t1
INNER JOIN `test` t2 ON t1.`ID`=t2.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `test` t3 ON t3.`ID`=t1.`ID` AND t3.`CREATED_AT` != t1.`CREATED_AT` AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t3.`CREATED_AT`, t1.`CREATED_AT`)) <= 3600 * 24
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t2.`CREATED_AT`, t1.`CREATED_AT`)) >= 3600 * 24 AND t3.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: That fiddle is returning 367 and 261 -- you used a slightly different data set in said fiddle than the OP -- The op has 2 entries for 367 which are not 24 hours apart but your fiddle has an extra one which is 24 hours and 30 seconds different.

Comment: Yes it is as per requirement i have just added.I need same .

Comment: It is returning what it is supposed to return -- anything with multiple entries separated by 24 hours. I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly...

Comment: @CharveeShah Are you looking to get results that are 24 hours apart where there are none < 24 hours? I've updated my query to do this -- see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bf493/31 -- changed to use TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(...)) since it needs to check < and >.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do is to use WHERE EXISTS with timestampdiff()

```
select ID 
from test t1
where exists(
  select 1 from test t2
  where t1.ID = t2.ID
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,t1.`CREATED AT`,t2.`CREATED AT`) >=24
);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f99fa/1)**

Comment: @CharveeShah Just need to add group by and in the fiddle and there are constitutive dates '2014-05-28 22:57:06' AND '2014-05-29 23:58:06' for 367 and this should be considered in the list http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8390d/6

Comment: Yes if the logic is to find the data having CREATED AT with a difference of > 24 hrs then its correct result, but if its between constitutive rows then with the above table structure all query will to determine the data, let me know if you have a better idea.

Comment: @CharveeShah If I am not wrong you are looking at the successive difference not the difference between min and max in this case you need to use JOINS something as http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bf493/52